# Database is gone! I don't know how to resolve the issue

Tags: apache2, mysql, lamp

I am running WordPress on ubuntu 16.04 Lamp and have my website running since 2018 without any issues. 
This morning the website was off with the error:

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1612
>   No such file or directory

I contacted my ISP that realized the

> /etc/mysql

and the

> /etc/mysql/my.cnf

files were gone. 
I have no idea how did this happen and would like to know if you have any idea how to fix this.

I have no backup and would love to be able to recover data.

My ISP tried to recover files using **testdisk** but was unsuccessful.

If I try to run mysql

```
mysql -u root -p
```

```
>Enter password:
```

I get this error

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

I would appreciate your help on the matter.

Comment: "I have no idea how did this happen". I would want to exactly know what has happened. Otherwise I could not trust my server anymore. Was it a hardware or software failure? Maybe even a compromised server / wordpress. I would not sleep well anymore without me knowing that.

Comment: Yes, that's how I feel.... I am not a specialist so it's driving me nuts. It happened without any apparent reasons :(

Comment: Files don't simply "vanish" for fun. I see three possibilities: Compromise (likely...it's Wordpress), hardware failure, and software failure. Note that software failure rarely causes data loss, so that's mighty unlikely. I think you have learned a valuable lesson here about keeping updates, and perhaps about Wordpress security. Beyond that, the question seems too vague to answer -- insufficient data.

Comment: What informations are you missing to know? 
I can add them to the thread? 
I am just not sure where to look...